# Pandas DataFrame column Datatypes df.T.T != df?

Tags: python, pandas

Bit of a general question but I have been using pandas for more than a year now and I keep getting into trouble when I have mixed types in pandas DataFrame columns.   I would Frequently have a DataFrame that comes in like this:

```
df2 =
             0          1          2           3           4
val_str      test       test       test        test       test
val_date     2014-01-15 2014-01-15 2014-01-15  2014-01-15 2014-01-15
val_float    1.5        1.5        1.5         1.5        1.5
val_int      1          1          1           1          1
```

as example generated by:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(5))
df['val_str'] = "test"
df['val_date']= datetime.datetime(2014,1,15)
df['val_bool'] = True
df['val_float'] = 1.5
df['val_int'] = 1
df2=df.T
```

Convoluted example, but the data comes from excel, csv etc and the a lot of times the the rows have consistent datatypes instead of the columns.

Pandas seems to handle its methods (mostly) well with this kind of data, but I frequently get unexpected results when selecting or trying to do boolean operations with the data.

Selecting data with e.g.

```
df2[2]['val_bool']  #eems to work without problem
```

seems to work well, even pulling rows out with e.g.:

```
df2.ix['val_bool']  # works fine
```

seems to work as expected.   I frequently run into problems trying to use this slice to further select data.

```
df2.ix['val_bool'].dtype
>>> dtype('O')
# trying boolean operations on this gives numeric results?
```

Is there any pandas guideline as to whether this could cause problems.  I have gone back to some of the initial tutorials and gathered that columns "should" have consistent datatypes.  Pandas' flexibility however allows you to do this, but some of the methods break?   I vaguely remember one of Wes McKinneys talk where he mentioned that:

```
df.T.T  != df
```

What are the differences and what should I be careful of when columns in DataFrame does not have consistent datatypes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Datatypes are column based. Doing a transpose `df.T` in a mixed-type frame, will necessarily convert to a type that can hold both types, meaning that a string and float will yield a `object` dtype.

so `df.T.T != df`, but, you can do: `df.T.T.convert_objects()` which will generally succeed in convert the `object` dtypes back to basic types.

Comment: Just to update this to reflect latest API changes, `convert_objects()` is deprecated, so use `infer_objects()` instead - thanks to the awesome pandas dev team.

Answer (score 5):

Under the hood, Pandas stores columns or groups of columns with the same dtype in a [Block](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/internals.py#L37). Thus, you can think of all the float columns being stored in one big array, and all the string columns in another array, etc.

When you have heterogenous column data, such as in `df2` above, every value is stored in an array of dtype `object`:

```
In [154]: df2._data
Out[154]: 
BlockManager
Items: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
Axis 1: Index([u'val_str', u'val_date', u'val_bool', u'val_float', u'val_int'], dtype='object')
ObjectBlock: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 5 x 5, dtype: object
```

This is the worst kind of dtype to have, since it enjoys none of the speed advantages offered by NumPy numeric types. Moreover, some NumPy (and maybe Pandas) functions raise  exceptions when operating on arrays of object dtype.

Even when you select a row which has only float values, you get back an array of object dtype:

```
In [149]: df2.loc['val_float'].dtype
Out[149]: dtype('O')
```

So the best way to take advantage of pandas is to load the data in a way which allows whole columns to have NumPy dtypes other than `object`, and never transpose (unless the entire DataFrame is of homogeneous dtype).

---

Note how the columns of `df` are segregated into blocks of different dtype. This is much better than `df2`'s one big `ObjectBlock`.

```
In [155]: df._data
Out[155]: 
BlockManager
Items: Index([u'val_str', u'val_date', u'val_bool', u'val_float', u'val_int'], dtype='object')
Axis 1: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64')
ObjectBlock: [val_str], 1 x 5, dtype: object
DatetimeBlock: [val_date], 1 x 5, dtype: datetime64[ns]
BoolBlock: [val_bool], 1 x 5, dtype: bool
FloatBlock: [val_float], 1 x 5, dtype: float64
IntBlock: [val_int], 1 x 5, dtype: int64
```